# Null pointer exception with Jax RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs, jboss7.x

I have written a simple piece of code to have JAX RS talk to JPA to retrieve a list of customers from the database. I keep getting a null pointer exception. Please could someone take a look at the log files below and advise what the error is stemming from.

Thanks

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "classicmodels", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")    
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer>  result = null;
        try{
        result = em.createQuery("select c from Customers c",Customer.class).getResultList();
        }
        catch(NoResultException e){

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
23:58:09,141 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/HelloWorld].[com.JaxActivator]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet com..JxActivator threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.CustomerResource.getAllCustomers(CustomerResource.java:31) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I guess line 31 is where you create the query, it seems your EntityManager is null

Comment: I thought @PersistenceContext(unitName = "classicmodels", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) injected the EntityManager?

Comment: This may be a potential cause: The @PersistenceContext annotation can be used on any CDI bean, EJB, Servlet, Servlet Listener, Servlet Filter, or JSF ManagedBean. If you don't use an EJB you will need to use a UserTransaction begin and commit transactions manually. A transaction is required for any of the create, update or delete methods of the EntityManager to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JPA nor JAX-RS processes [`@PersistentContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation in runtime. It is just ignored and the `em` property remains set to `NULL` - that's why the NPE. You should add some EJB container to the application, for example [OpenEJB](http://tomee.apache.org/) or get rid of the annotation and instantiate `em` inside your JAX-RS resource (and start/stop the transaction).

Comment: I was having a similar problem using JBoss AS 7 - turns out I forgot to create the beans.xml file in WEB-INF. Adding this solved my injection problem.